# How to count the number of instances a pattern is matched in Redshift/Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

For demo purposes, say I have a large table (billion rows+) in Redshift, with two fields:
`id` and `win`. `win` can be `0` or `1`.

Is there an efficient way to count the number of times a win sequence of the following type is matched: `1000`? In other words, if the table contained this data:

```
+-----+-----+
| id  | win |
+-----+-----+
|  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  1  |
|  2  |  0  |
|  3  |  1  |
|  4  |  0  |
|  5  |  0  |
|  6  |  0  |
|  7  |  1  |
+-----+-----+
```

the query would return 1.

I guess this question can be answered in **PostgreSQL**, and possibly in SQL.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean id = 3 with win = 1, is followed by id 4, 5, 6 all with win = 0?

Comment: Yeah, id gaps should be ignored.

Comment: Do you mean id = 13 with win = 1, followed by id 15, 16, 17 all with win = 0, does count or not? (if no id = 14 exists.)

Comment: It counts as well.

Comment: There's workarounds for that if it's a problem anyway I think.

Comment: What is your expected output? Its not clear from your question.

Comment: What is not clear? The expected output above would be 1, as I wrote already. If there's a sequence of wins that matches the sequence in question, that would increment the result.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lead(win, 1) over (order by id) as win_1,
             lead(win, 2) over (order by id) as win_2,
             lead(win, 3) over (order by id) as win_3
      from t
     ) t
where win = 1 and win_1 = 0 and win_2 = 0 and win_3 = 0;
```

I think Postgres will effectively use an index on `(id, win)`.  But on billions of rows, this will not be fast.

Comment: I'm wondering about the performance of this... at a glance it seems like it blows up the number of entries by the length of the streak. Thanks anyway. I'm going to try it in Redshift.

Comment: Managed to take up all diskspace on my Redshift cluster and the query blew up :)

Comment: @KristianD'Amato . . . Wow!  It would probably work on a much smaller machine using Postgres with an index.